# Pcraster - python - reading stack of maps

Tags: python

I have a stack of maps as follows:

[image: list of .map files]

They are the outputs of every 720 timesteps of a certain dynamic model
I would like to import / read those maps as input of other dynamic models.

What should I do?

(I've tried timeiput but I don't get how to use it correctly).

Comment: can you please actually paste the list of filenames in the question.. it makes it easier to understand the question

Answer (score 0):

If the stack of maps is in a particular directory, you can use `os.path` and read all files in that directory.

```
from os import listdir
from os.path import isfile, join
onlyfiles = [f for f in listdir(mypath) if isfile(join(mypath, f))]
```

`onlyfiles` is a list of files in that directory.

Since the names follow a complex pattern(of difference of 720 in the ending). I think this is best way to go through all files.

Comment: Actually, I was thinking to read the input for different steps (i.e. radar rainfall image or groundwater recharge) to a hydrological model or to modflow model (PCraster extension).

I wonder if I am reading the file like your suggestions, the dynamic framework can be able to handle the input?

That's why I am still confusing with the "readmap" and the "timeinput" of PCRaster. But the example in their manual is missing so it is hard to make sure of it.

Thank you anyway!

Comment: if you are specific about generating filenames in that pattern you can do so by taking first string and adding 720 to each time.